# What is the difference between in sample error and training error, and intuition of optimism?

Tags: variance, error, bias, intuition, in-sample

In the book [Elements of Statistical Learning](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/) in Chapter 7 (page 228), the training error is defined as:
$$
\overline{err} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}{L(y_i,\hat{f}(x_i))}
$$

Whereas in-sample error is defined as
$$
Err_{in} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}{E_{Y^0}[L(Y_{i}^{0},\hat{f}(x_i))|\tau]}
$$

> The $Y^0$ notation indicates that we observe N new response values at
>   each of the training points $x_i, i = 1, 2, . . . ,N$.

Which seems to be exactly the same as training error because training error is also calculated i.e by computing the response of the training set using the fitted estimate $\hat{f}(x)$. I have checked [this](https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-intuition-behind-the-difference-between-extra-sample-error-in-sample-error-and-training-error-as-discussed-by-Tibshirani-et-al-in-the-ESL-book) and [this](https://tgmstat.wordpress.com/2013/05/22/model-selection-and-model-assessment-according-to-1-part-1/) explanation of this concept, but could not understand the difference between training error and in-sample error, and why optimism is not always 0:
$$
op\equiv Err_{in}-\overline{err}
$$

So how are the errors $Err_{in}$ and $\overline{err}$ different, and what is the intuitive understanding of optimism in this context?

Additionally, what does the author mean by "usually biased downward" in the statement:

> This is typically positive since err is usually biased downward as an estimate of prediction error.

while describing Optimism (Elements of Statistical Learning, page 229)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$Y^0$ in this setup has random part, e.g. with additive error $\varepsilon\sim N(0,\sigma_\varepsilon^2)$. So for fixed $(x,y)\in\mathcal{T}$, new response $Y^0$ to the predictor $x$ needs not to be the same as the corresponding training response $y$, hence the expectation $\operatorname{E}_{Y^0}$. "Biased downward" just means that $\overline{\mathrm{err}}$ is on average less than the true prediction error.

Comment: Right, so is the random component the irreducible random error present in the data being modeled, and in $\topline{err}$ the $y_i$ is the mean of data points not including the random error $\epsilon$

Comment: @SpeedBirdNine: $y_i$ belongs to a fixed sample $\mathcal{T}$ that has been observed, and $\overline{\mathrm{err}}$ is mean of the losses over $\mathcal{T}$

Comment: I think it should not be `needs not to be the same` but `doesn't need to be the same`...

Comment: @FrancescoBoi: I think these two phrases are semantically the same? That said, assuming continuous error, a more technically correct term to use is "almost surely not the same".

Comment: When I first read it, I interpreted `needs not to be` as `not` being the negation of `be`, i.e. `need to be different`, not of `need`. Now I see what you mean, honestly I do not know but I understood what you meant now.