# In practice, do we distinguish between "in-sample" and "training" error?

Tags: error, training-error, in-sample

In Elements of Statistical Learning, it distinguishes between "in-sample" and "training" error (Frankly, I found the chapter on errors to be very confusing, especially with how they use the different error terminology). Also see the question asked here: [What is the difference between in sample error and training error, and intuition of optimism?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/228394/what-is-the-difference-between-in-sample-error-and-training-error-and-intuition)

But it seems in a lot situations, when people refer to "in-sample" error in practice, they mean the training error, and the 2 are used interchangeably. Is this typically the case?