# What is the difference between in sample error and generalization error?

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, mathematical-statistics

As in this question:[What is the difference between in sample error and training error, and intuition of optimism?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/228394/what-is-the-difference-between-in-sample-error-and-training-error-and-intuition)

In the book [Elements of Statistical Learning](http://statweb.stanford.edu/%7Etibs/ElemStatLearn/) in Chapter 7 (page 228), given a data set $\mathcal{T}=\{(x_i,y_i)\}, i=1,\dots, N$ the generalization error of a model $\hat{f}$ is defined by

$$
Err_{\mathcal{T}}=E_{X^0, Y^0}[L(Y^0, \hat{f}(X^0))|\mathcal{T}]
$$

Whereas in-sample error is defined as
$$
Err_{in} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}{E_{Y^0}[L(Y_{i}^{0},\hat{f}(x_i))|\tau]}
$$

> The $Y^0$ notation indicates that we observe N new response values at
> each of the training points $x_i, i = 1, 2, . . . ,N$.

the training error is defined as:
$$
\overline{err} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}{L(y_i,\hat{f}(x_i))}
$$

Question:

(1) What is the difference between generalization error and in-sample error? How to understand them?

(2) Why do we define AIC and BIC for estimation of in-sample error rather than the generalization error?

(3) For any loss function, do we always have a generalization error that is larger than training error? Is there theoretical proof? I only found the proof of mean square loss.

Comment: Can you share your source for (3)?