# How to express out of sample MSE in terms of training MSE?

Tags: machine-learning

Consider the context of [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/306387/280102):

It claims that

$$E[\hat{MSE}_{out}] = E[\hat{MSE}_{in}] + 2/N\sum_{i=1}^NCov(y_i, \hat{y_i})$$

However, the reference (ESLII Section 7.4; PDF page 248) does not prove this. According to [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/228394/what-is-the-difference-between-in-sample-error-and-training-error-and-intuition), $2/N\sum_{i=1}^NCov(y_i, \hat{y_i})$ is actually the difference between in-sample error and the training error. (In the first post, $\hat{MSE}_{out}$ is the out-of-sample estimate of the MSE, which does not appear in section 7.4)

Can we prove the equation in the first post if the model is assumed to be consistent?